# Angular page redirection if returned value is false

Tags: javascript, angularjs

in my controller i have this code that simply get the `logged_status`.

```js
app.controller('dashboardCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $http) {
  $scope.displaySN = '';
  $scope.studentNumber = sessionStorage.getItem('student_number');
  $scope.get_logged_status = sessionStorage.getItem('logged_status');
  console.log("Dashboard Page Logged Status: " + $scope.get_logged_status);

  if(!$scope.get_logged_status)
  {
    console.log('should redirect because false');
  }else{
    console.log('should stay because true');
  }

})
```

it is getting the correct value but when i test the value of it and log a certain statement, im getting an unexpected result. in the image below, instead of getting `should redirect because false` because  `$scope.get_logged_status` is valued `false`, im getting the opposite result. Help Please. Am i coding it wrong?

Please see image here

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
 if($scope.get_logged_status=="false")
```

maybe the item `logged_status` in the `sessionStorage` is considered as `string` not a `boolean`, so it returns always true

Answer (score 0):

I think `sessionStorage.getItem` returns a string, so your string `false` actually evaluates to `true`.

You can try using `if($scope.get_logged_status == 'false')`

Comment: I set it using $scope.logged_status = sessionStorage.setItem('logged_status', true);

Comment: can you please confirm it

Comment: ah yes it is returning string console.log(typeof $scope.get_logged_status);